# LINQ Group by performing join across multiple tables/classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, c#-4.0

I have a table structure in my DB like this:

```
Items <=  User  => Transactions
```

So in C# mapped classes User contains a collection of Items and Transactions... (1 to many relationship)..

So now what I've done is following:

```
   var filteredProducts = ctx.Transactions.Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == 
    firstRequest.SearchedUserID)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.TransactionDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.TransactionID ).Select(x => new ResultItem()
    {
     TransactionID = x.Key,
     SaleNumber = x.Sum(y => y.QuantityPurchased)                 
     })
     .ToList();
```

So as you can see I'm grouping by data in transactions table... Now what I would like to do here, if it's possible, in an easy manner to go across the User table into Items table and select a specific property that I need from it for that grouped item, which is CurrentPrice, and the table Transactions doesn't contains this data...

So in the select statement I'd like to pull out the CurrentPrice property like this :

```
.Select(x => new ResultItem()
        {
         TransactionID = x.Key,
         SaleNumber = x.Sum(y => y.QuantityPurchased),
         CurrentPrice = // somehow go to Items table and pick up this data 
         })
         .ToList();
```

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Does `Transactions` has any reference to `Items`? Let's say that a customer has purchased totally 4 items, 2 items A,1 item B and 1 item C. Furthermore, let's suppose that customer initally purchased 1 iteam A and 1 item B and then pruchased 1 item A and 1 item C. That being said Customer has a list of 4 items and a list of 2 transactions. Is there any connection between each transaction and the items customer purchased?

Comment: @Christos no ,theres no reference between items and transactions, they're simply linked via User table..

Comment: Can you post the schemas? It is weird to me that you are grouping by `TransactionID`. By definition, ID should be unique.

Comment: @User987 If you can't tell what the customer bought by seeing a transaction associated with a customer, I don't see how you could find that you are looking for. Is the case as I described above or the system has been designed in another way? Specifically, do you have a transaction for multiple items or one transaction per item? This is not clear to me, since you group by `TransactionID`. Isn't this a primary key to the Transactions table? If so, why do you group by `TransactionID`? Could you please post the schema details for Items, Users, Transactions and their underlying relationships?

Comment: Are you want to `CurrentPrice` as then some of  `items` which is belong to `SearchedUserID`?@User987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I get your table schema you should start your query from user table while you are filtering your data by `SearchUserId` so, first get data with User table relations

**Note:** As I don't know your tables schema `UserId` considered as `User` table primary key and `Transactions` and `Items` tables foreign key in this sample code

```
    var result = (from usr in ctx.User
                 where  usr.UserId == firstRequest.SearchedUserID
                 select new {
                    UserId = usr.UserId,
                    Transactions = usr.Transactions,
                    Items = usr.Items
                 })
```

Then try to filter,Group,... on data. But if you want to select what you mentioned in your question, you should have a relation between `Items` and `Transactions` tables.